# BeautifulSoup and &nbsp;

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

My Code:

```
html = "<tag>&nbsp;</tag>"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print BeautifulSoup(html).renderContents()
```

The output:

```
<tag>┬á</tag>
```

Desired output:

```
<tag>&nbsp;</tag>
```

BeautifulSoup seems to be replaced my breaking space html escape with a unicode character that means the same thing. But that doesn't make it all the way through my system and ends up becoming a non-breaking space and thus not doing what I wanted. Is there a way to tell BeautifulSoup not to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `encode_contents` instead of `renderContents`, or `encode` or `prettify`. They all support the [`formatter`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters) argument, and pass `'html'` as formatter:

```
html = "<tag>&nbsp;</tag>"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print BeautifulSoup(html).encode_contents(formatter='html')
```

produces:

```
<tag>&nbsp;</tag>
```