# Python - Beautiful Soup - How to Replace a String With a Non-Breaking Space?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following HTML fragment:

```
<div><span>This is some text.</span></div>
```

I want to replace the `span` within the `div` tags with a single non-breaking space (i.e. `&nbsp;`), resulting in the following HTML **SOURCE**:

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

I tried

```
soup.div.span.replace_with('&nbsp;')
```

but it resulted in

```
<div>&amp;nbsp;</div>
```

I also tried

```
soup.div.span.replace_with(' ') // single space character
```

but it resulted in

```
<div> </div>
```

How can I insert the non-breaking space entity?

Comment: Did you tried ``str.replace()``?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224863/beautifulsoup-and-nbsp, same to go into the right direction

Comment: @VishnuUpadhyay: this is a *HTML tree*, not a string. The `<span>` element is being replaced here, not string contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&nbsp;` entity stands for the [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://codepoints.net/U+00A0) character, use that as BeautifulSoup treats all text contents as Unicode:

```
soup.div.span.replace_with(u'\xa0')
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''<div><span>This is some text.</span></div>''')
>>> soup.div.span.replace_with(u'\xa0')
<span>This is some text.</span>
>>> soup.encode_contents(formatter='html')
'<html><body><div>&nbsp;</div></body></html>'
```

Note that I needed to use an [output formatter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters) to force BeautifulSoup to use entities in the output; the default is to use the literal character (which is fine for browsers).